# Checkbox parent child relationship android

Tags: android, checkbox, parent-child

I want to create a parent-child relationship for Checkbox in Android as per the material design guidelines given in https://material.io/components/selection-controls#checkboxes.

I want a parent Checkbox under which there will be child checkboxes and When the parent checkbox is checked, all child checkboxes are checked.

If a parent checkbox is unchecked, all child checkboxes are unchecked.

If some, but not all, child checkboxes are checked, the parent checkbox becomes an indeterminate checkbox.

I checked developer docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox but there is no information about this.

Also, I checked material design docs https://material.io/develop/android/components/checkbox/, they have given the guideline to do the same, however, they haven't given any example project to do the same.

I tried creating a Parent-Child relationship with the checkbox using nesting but that didn't work. Does anyone have an idea about how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a listener on your 'parent' CheckBox, to toggle the 'child' CheckBoxes when the state of your 'parent' CheckBox changes.

See here to set-up the listener:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)

Here's an example:

```
    val childCheckBoxes = listOf(checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3)
    parentCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        childCheckBoxes.forEach {
            it.isChecked = isChecked
        }
    }
```

At the same time, it sounds like you need to add listeners to each child CheckBox, to update the parent CheckBox state - such that if any of the child CheckBoxes are checked, the parent is also checked. Bear in mind that if you call
`parentCheckBox.isChecked = true`
it will also call the OnCheckedChangeListener of `parentCheckBox`, and you'll end up with infinite recursion. So you'll probably want to disable the OnCheckedChangeListener when setting `isChecked` like this. That could look like this:

```
val theRealListener = { _, isChecked ->
        childCheckBoxes.forEach {
            it.isChecked = isChecked
        }
    }
parentCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
parentCheckBox.isChecked = whatever
parentCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(theRealListener)
```

The 'indeterminate' state is not included in the default Android CheckBox - it can only be 'checked' or 'unchecked'. You will need to use something custom for this. Perhaps this library will be useful to you:
https://github.com/sevar83/indeterminate-checkbox

If you decide to use this library, it looks like you will need to use `setOnStateChangedListener` rather than `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, but the idea stays the same.